# ubuntu 19.04 hangs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I have a Gigabyte motherboard B360M D3H. System hangs on shutdown but reboots OK. I have tried shutdown via terminal (shutdown -P etc), same result.

I disabled `quiet splash` and observed screen. All looks OK finishing with `Reached target Power-off` but power stays on with reduced fan speed.

After a few minutes, there is a further message:

```
INFO:  task systemd-shutdow: 1 blocked for more than 120 seconds #20ubuntu Non tainted 5.0.0-19-generic


“echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs” disables this message
```

This message repeats indefinitely every few minutes.

There have been a couple of kernel updates while I have had this problem – no change.

Note that I have had this problem since changing out the motherboard/CPU/RAM after a hardware failure. The old M/B was B75M-D3H. The system was fine before that. I use integrated graphics.

Output of `sudo lshw -C memory`

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F12
       date: 03/14/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2666C16/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: F1068B79
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920) [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2666C16/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 2
          serial: F80696EE
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920) [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 44
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 45
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 46
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 9MiB
       capacity: 9MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1216000-a1217fff memory:a121c000-a121cfff
```

Comment: Hopefully you installed in UEFI mode. Now, also check UEFI settings for some sort of OS selection setting, change it to "Linux" or "Other", depending on the hardware and try again.

Comment: No, I am in legacy mode

Comment: Any special reason for the Legacy mode?

Comment: Not really. UEFI wasn't so widespread when I formatted the SSD some years ago. I have been wondering if the problem would go away if I reinstalled using UEFI. I note that another poster on this site has the same problem with the same motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your BIOS on the new motherboard. In `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.

The latest BIOS is F13, dated 6/27/2019. See https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B360M-D3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios to get the update.

Go to http://www.memtest.org or https://www.memtest86.com/ (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have written that I had already checked that my BIOS is the latest version - f12.

Comment: Your second link requires UEFI and I don't think your first link supports Coffee Lake and DDR4. I will look into this.

Comment: @habana At the 2nd link, their older **MemTest86 v4** will work with non-uefi configs. Download it there.

Comment: Thank you but v4 doesn't support DDR4 according to the specs

Comment: @habana Where did you see that spec?

Comment: @habana if you temporarily flip your motherboard to uefi, couldn't you run the newer memtest? Why do you run in non-uefi mode?

Comment: It is on the Features tab of the link you kindly provided. Gosh, I didn't think of a temporary move to UEFI. I will try it.  I installed in non-UEFI several years ago before it was widespread and it seemed easier at the time. Obviously a poor decision in retrospect.

Comment: I ran Memtest v8.2. Zero errors after 4 passes on default settings so I guess the RAM is good.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: My apologies for the poor formatting above. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: @habana Good news on the RAM test. Try this... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and see if you can shutdown all the way in that configuration. That'll eliminate a problem with your Ubuntu installation on your current HDD/SSD.

Comment: Yes I can shut down but not quite as usual. I get the 'remove media then press enter' message. I do so but the message comes back and the system shuts down after a minute or so. In other systems I have had, the system shuts down immediateky

Comment: @habana You're correct. It should shutdown quickly. Sounds more and more like you've got a hardware issue. Were you still in UEFI mode, or had you switched back to legacy BIOS? Try UEFI mode shutdown with Ubuntu Live.

Comment: Actually I don't have to switch between UEFI and Legacy. I merely have to enable UEFI CSM. However, there is a Storage Boot Option Control which selects the ‘ROM for the storage device controller’. This can be disabled or set to legacy or UEFI. I couldn’t get the live USB to boot with it set to UEFI. On the other hand, my SSD boots up quicker with it set to UEFI. Maybe the latter mode enables AHCI.

Comment: @habana but setting the controller to UEFI should require that you change your SSD partition table to GPT. Also, the USB flash wouln't boot 'cause it probably wasn't created in UEFI mode.  I don't know... one of your settings is screwball on this new motherboard. I'd just start over... backup your files, set your computer to UEFI, drop a GPT partition table onto the SSD (this will wipe the SSD), and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: To quote the Mobo manual, UEFI CSM (Compatibility Support Module) supports the legacy boot process. Since my previous post I disabled CSM to force UEFI on the live USB boot. It behaved exactly as previously - strange shutdown. Not sure, therefore, that a reinstallation will solve this. I already have GPT and 10GB unallocated so hopefully I can tack on an EFI partition and disable the old boot flag. Anyway, thank you for all your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, I checked before posting that I had the latest BIOS. That very day, but obviously after I looked, Gigabyte released an update to fix an Intel security problem.

I have now updated my BIOS and the problem has gone away. So, either my old BIOS was corrupted in some way or Gigabyte fixed it in the new release.

Thank you to those who took the time to asist me with this, notably heynnema.

Comment: Since my answer indicated a possible BIOS fix, it should really be the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, when I shutdown my Ubuntu 19.10, the Ubuntu stopped, but pc still working.

I have clear my BIOS setting, then update to last version from F13 to F14. My motherboard is Gigabyte H310 D3 rev 1.0. CPU Intel 9400F.

Problem is resolved.